# How to assign results from printf statement to a variable (for leading zeroes)?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I'm writing a shell script (Bash on Mac OS X) to rename a bunch of image files. I want the results to be:

```
frame_001
frame_002
frame_003
```

etc.

Here is my code:

```
let framenr=$[1 + (y * cols * resolutions) + (x * resolutions) + res]
echo $framenr:
let framename=$(printf 'frame_%03d' $framenr)
echo $framename
```

`$framenr` looks correct, but `$framename` always becomes `0`. Why?

Answer (score 22):

The `let` command forces arithmetic evaluation, and the referenced "variable" does not exist, so you get the default value 0.

```bash
y=5
x=y; echo $x        # prints: y
let x=y; echo $x    # prints: 5
```

Do this instead:

```bash
framenr=$(( 1 + (y * cols * resolutions) + (x * resolutions) + res ))
echo $framenr:

# or
framename=$(printf 'frame_%03d' $framenr)

echo $framename
```

And there's `printf -v` to avoid subshell invocation:

```bash
# with bash 3.1+
printf -v framename 'frame_%03d' $framenr
```

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf) for `printf -v`, available from [bash 3.1+](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2005-12/msg00003.html).

I recall reading somewhere that `$[ ]` is deprecated. Use `$(( ))` instead.

Comment: Here `printf -v` uses the bash builtin `printf`, see [Bash Builtin Commands#printf manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf).

Comment: `framename=$(printf ...)` will also use the builtin printf